# Why doesn't RewriteRequest work even after refering to the link in sitemap?

Tags: web-applications, scala, lift

I have the following rewrite in Boot.boot(). This is based on the instructions found in the [URL Rewriting](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/URL_Rewriting) section in the Lift Wiki.

```
LiftRules.statefulRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("CreateAndEditRewrite") {
  case RewriteRequest(
        ParsePath("models" :: "createEdit" :: state :: Nil, _, _,_), _, _) => {
      Console.println("Rewriting path: models/createEdit/Create to createEdit.html")
      val rewriteResp = RewriteResponse(
        "models/createEdit" :: Nil, "html" // Use webapp/models/creteEdit.html
      )
      Console.println("Response refers to URL " + rewriteResp.path + " with parameters " + rewriteResp.params.toList.map(x => "" + x.key + "=" + x.value + ", "))
      rewriteResp

  }
})
```

To make sure everything is accessible a made sure SiteMap permitted access to "models/createEdit/create" and "models/createEdit" with the following lines.

```
val entries =
     Menu(Loc("models", List(""), "Models"),
         Menu(Loc("createEditM", List("models","createEdit","Create"), "[NEW]Create Model", loggedIn)),
         Menu(Loc("createEditMXX", List("models","createEdit"), "[NEW]Create Model", loggedIn)) ) ::
     User.sitemap

// Build SiteMap
LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries:_*))
LiftRules.passNotFoundToChain = true //if a URL isn't found pass responsability to the container
```

Yet, the second menu option works while the first yelds a "HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /models/createEdit/Create" on the container level.

The following `println` appear on the console

```
Rewriting path: models/createEdit/Create to createEdit.html
Response refers to URL ParsePath(List(models/createEdit),html,true,false) with parameters List()
INFO - Service request (GET) /models/createEdit/Create returned 0, took 11 Milliseconds
```

which means the rewrite was triggered.

I'm using Lift 2.4-M3 with Scala 2.9.0-1.

Anyone has any idea what is the problem?

Thanks.

**Edit**: changed code sample and added console output to make what is happening clearer.

Comment: note that the first menu("createEditM") is never accessed, since all the requests /models/createEdit/? are redirected to /models/createEdit

Comment: @coubeatczech - The _menu_ "createEditM" appears in the interface and I can click it. Since that click results in a new request, the _rerite_ jumps in resulting in a _404_. I know the _rewrite_ is triggered because "Rewriting path: models/createEdit/Create to createEdit.html" gets printed in the console. What is never found is the models/createEdit.html snippet. :(
Maybe I should edit my question with these extra details.

Comment: Did a new edit to show that the Rewrite gets triggerd and even creates a response that should include models/createEdit.html.

Comment: Anyone thinks there is lack of detail or even that I should ask this somewhere else? I'm now reading and debugging Lift's own source as a submodule of my project but understanding it takes time. Anyway, any input is appreciated. :(

Comment: OK...I've given up on the preivous approach and decided to use http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html#toc-Subsection-3.2.7 and http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-7.html#toc-Subsection-7.6.2 to do what I want. I still have a problem since I want to call a *template* and these examples call snippets. We shall see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use the Rewrite stuff.  It's low level and generally isn't necessary.

If you want a parameterized Menu entry, use Menu.param.  See http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html#toc-Subsection-3.2.7

Comment: Hello David. Since my implementation is working and I'm doing other stuff for some time I've been postponing giving a reply to this. When I have the time (that will happen when I add code that handles all the other possible states that the page may have, I will post the results here). Thanks for answering though. :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve the rwriting problem I ended up deleting the rewrite rule and implementing a custom Loc object with the following code.

```
package pt.cnbc.wikimodels.client

package object sitemapTweaks {
  import net.liftweb.common.Full
  import net.liftweb.http.{RewriteResponse, ParsePath, RewriteRequest}
  import net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc
  import net.liftweb.common.Box
  import net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc.{
  Link, LinkText, LocParam, Hidden
  }
  import net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc.If._
  import pt.cnbc.wikimodels.snippet.User
  import net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc._

  // verification if the user is logged
  val loggedIn = If(() => User.loggedIn_?, "You must be logged in.")

  object ModelPageLoc extends Loc[ModelPageState] {
    var state:ModelPageState = defaultValue.openTheBox
    def name: String = "CreateEDitWithState"

    def link = new Link[ModelPageState]("models" :: "createEdit" :: "Create" :: Nil)

    def text = "Model handling" + defaultValue

    def params: List[LocParam[ModelPageState]] = List(loggedIn)

    override def rewrite = Full({
      case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(List("models", "createEdit", _state), _, _, _), _, _) => {
        _state match {
          case "Create" => {
            state = Create
            (RewriteResponse(List("models", "createEdit")), Create)
          }
          case _ => {
            state = Edit
            (RewriteResponse(List("models", "createEdit")), Edit)
          }
        }
      }
    })
    def defaultValue: Box[ModelPageState] = Full(Create)
  }

  sealed abstract class ModelPageState

  case object Create extends ModelPageState

  case object Edit extends ModelPageState
}
```

With this object impleemented I only had to add a sitemap reference:

```
val entries =
     Menu(Loc("models", List(""), "Models"),
         Menu(Loc("createEditMXX", List("models","createEdit"), "[NEW]Create Model", loggedIn)),
         Menu(ModelPageLoc), //This line calls the customized Loc object
     User.sitemap

// Build SiteMap
LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries:_*))
LiftRules.passNotFoundToChain = true //if a URL isn't found pass responsability to the container
```

And it's done!

Comment: This is very verbose and I really wish there was an easier way to do it. For that reason I will leave this question open a bit longer, to see if anyone comes up with a solution to the problem I had in the rewrite rule (simpler).